# Using SQL Server, how to return a list from a While loop, and should I be using a While loop?

Tags: sql-server

I have table A, with columns `Id` and `ParentId`. Given an `Id`, I want to return all `ParentId`.

Meaning, given an `Id`, I want to return all entries' `ParentId`, and then I want to check to see if the recorded `ParentId` is entered into the table as an Id, if so I want to find it's `ParentId`, etc...

For example, if I have the simple example of a table like:

```
Id | ParentID
---+---------
1    0    
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4 
6    5
7    6
```

My query to print all the parents of `Id=7` looks like this:

```
DECLARE @ParentId INT;

SET @ParentId = 7;

WHILE(@ParentId > 0)
BEGIN 
  SELECT @ParentId = ParentId
  FROM A
  WHERE Id = @ParentID

  PRINT @ParentId
END
```

This query prints all the `ParentId`. But, is there a way to return the IDs? In that, if I was calling this query from PHP I would want to get a list of the ParentIds, but my query doesn't actually return anything.

Additionally, I wonder if a while loop is the correct solution. Would a recursive query be faster? If so, any advice on how to convert this to a recursive query?

*Edit

I need to access the list of ParentIds from PHP. Now I'm trying to build a comma-delimited list of Ids to return from the query, which I can later parse in PHP. However, the below query gives me error:

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

```
DECLARE @ParentId INT, @ParentList varchar(max);

    SET @ParentId = 7;

    WHILE(@ParentId > 0)
    BEGIN 
      SELECT @ParentId = ParentId
      FROM A
      WHERE Id = @ParentID

      SET @ParentList = @ParentList | CAST(@ParentId as varchar(20)) | ','; 
    END
    RETURN @ParentList;
```

What should I do to return a list? Additionally, how can I get the returned value when I execute this statement in PHP?

Comment: While loops and recursive method calls are equivalent.

Comment: Are the equivalent in terms of performance?

Comment: A while loop is always going to suffer from a performance standpoint. Often times a recursive cte will not suffer the same performance penalty. From your description I would think a recursive cte is just what you need.

Comment: I'm not going to answer that specifically in details here, I recommend taking at look at this [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182314/recursion-or-while-loops). But tl;dr, implementing it using recursion is not going to help, although it wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way to return the IDs after while loop is to create table variable to store them in process

```
declare @parents table
(
  LVL int primary key identity(1,1), -- [optional] level in hierarchy
  ParentID int
)
DECLARE @ParentId INT;
SET @ParentId = 7;
WHILE(@ParentId > 0)
BEGIN 
  SELECT @ParentId=ParentId
  FROM   A
  WHERE  Id=@ParentID

  -- PRINT @ParentId
  if (@ParentId > 0)
  insert into @parents (ParentID) values (@ParentId)
END

select * from @parents
```

if you want a recursive query, try search for `recursive cte in sql-server`

it is possible to create a `@parentList varchar(max)` variable and return result as a string `'6,5,4,3,2,1'` and split it on client-side, but that format is not useful in db

```
DECLARE @ParentId INT, @ParentList varchar(max) = '';
-- @ParentList should be initialized with non-NULL value

SET @ParentId = 7;

WHILE(@ParentId > 0)
BEGIN 
  SELECT @ParentId = ParentId
  FROM A
  WHERE Id = @ParentID

  SET @ParentList = @ParentList + CAST(@ParentId as varchar(20)) + ','; 
END
select @ParentList;
```

Comment: There is no concept of building a list within the loop, and then returning the list after the loop finishes?

Comment: @ab11, it is a relational database, so it works with tables. it is possible to create a `@parentList varchar(max)` variable and return result as a string `'6,5,4,3,2,1'` and split it on client-side, but that format is not useful in db. why don't  simply return a set of values?

Comment: I am calling this query from php. I need it to return a list of ids, so your suggestion seems like exactly what I'd like to do. However I'm having trouble getting it to work. Can you look at the edit I made to my question?

Comment: @ab11, what is context? is it a scalar function? if it is a simple query, not a function, try `select @ParentList` intstead of `RETURN @ParentList`

Comment: It is a simple function. I have php code that constructs a query and calls the database. And I want to pull the list of parentIds from the result.

Comment: @ab11, did you try`select @ParentList`? Does it work?

Comment: It seems to. But now I'm having trouble concatenating the Strings. If I do `SET @ParentList = ParentId`, it will return an Id. But nothing gets returned if I try to build the list with `SET @ParentList += ParentId`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77035/discussion-between-ab11-and-ash).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  child.ParentID
FROM    A child
            INNER JOIN A parent
            ON child.Id = parent.ParentID
```

**Result**

```
0  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7
```

To return list of string

```
DECLARE @List NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @List = COALESCE(@List + ',', '') + child.ParentID
FROM    A child
            INNER JOIN A parent
            ON child.Id = parent.ParentID

SELECT  @List
```

**Result**
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: Can you please explain why this gives the solution that @ab11 is looking for?

Comment: it is not a solution. query is equal to `select ParentID from A`

Comment: I add COALESCE function to return result as a list of id

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, if you can create and maintain two tables (one for parents, one for children) you can take advantage of the relationship between the two data sets. Hence the R in RDBMS. If you had 3 parents with 3 children each it might look like this:

```
tblParents.ParentID
1 --Children are 1,2,3
2 --Children are 4,5,6
3 --Children are 7,8,9

tblChildren.ChildID, tblChildren.ParentID
1,1 --Parent 1's children
2,1
3,1
4,2 --Parent 2's children
5,2
6,2
7,3 --Parent 3's children
8,3
9,3
```

So back to your original question. In this scenario, if you know the ChildID you can JOIN the Child and Parent tables together using the ParentID. Then you can get at the Parent information by only knowing the ChildID.

The other comments are answering your question but not solving your data modeling problem!

Hope that helps!